# Clarification of a concept in Permutation

Tags: permutations

*Statement 1*

**No. of ways in which $(m+n+p)!$ different things can be divivded into different groups containing m,n & p things respectively. is $(m+n+p)!/m!n!p!$**

*Statement 2*

**If $m=n=p$ and the groups have identical qualititive characteristic then the no. of groups=$(3n)!/(n!)^3*3!)$**

How this '$3!$' arrives? Why doesnot substituting the values work in *statement 2*?

Comment: We would be counting the $3!$ permutations of the 3 identical groups. So the answer needs to be reduced (divided) by $3!$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are distributing *distinct* objects to basically *identical* groups which may be *distinguished/identified* if group sizes differ.

*Statement 1*: Suppose 6 objects ABCDEF are distributed in 3-2-1 pattern, e.g. ABC | DE | F

Obviously there are 6! permutations, but we need to remove the permutation **within** each group, thus $\dfrac{6!}{3!2!1!}$

The groups get *distinguished/identified* by the *size* of the group.

*Statement 2*: Now suppose we instead distribute in 2-2-2 pattern, e.g. AB | CD | EF

Again there are 6! permutations, and we need to divide by $(2!)^3$ in the previous pattern.

But apart from that, there is **no difference** between AB | CD | EF and, say, CD| EF | AB , i.e. the groups canot be *distinguished/identified*.

So we also need to remove permutations **between groups**, hence division by 3!

**NOTE**

As a further aid to understanding, suppose the distribution was in the pattern 4-1-1, we would not be able to *distinguish/identify* only 2 of the groups, and the answer would be $\dfrac{6!}{4!1!1*2!}$

Answer (score 0):

It is because the groups are identical in statement $1$ and identical in statement $2$ that the difference arises.

The difference can be seen in the following example:

There is exactly $1$ way to split a group of three people into three groups of size $1$, $\frac{3!}{1!1!1!3!}$. However if each group is distinct there are $6$ ways to split them, $\frac{3!}{1!1!1!}$

Comment: Could you explain a little more with the same example?